# Understanding SPICE code in Chan Transformer in LTSpice

Tags: transformer, spice

Taken from here:
http://ltwiki.org/?title=Transformers

[image]

I am having trouble understanding how the Chan core is actually linking in with the coils.

Does anyone understand what the SPICE code is doing here? Especially in the second half? It may just be lack of familiarity with the syntax or keywords being used.

Xp and Xs are supposed to be coils so I only expect two terminals, but there are three terminals and the Chan core mysteriously links to this third terminal.

But if that is the case then what are the actual Xs and Xp components in the simulation and how is it being interpreted by LTSpice? It seems like it has something to do with the "Winding" keyword but I haven't been able to find out what that is or how it works.

Is the third terminal special terminal activated by the "Winding" keyword that is meant specifically to determine the core? But if it is, then why does the core have two terminals (the other of which is permanently connected to GND via the paramterization in the first half of the code) since there's no current flowing through the core?

Comment: Do you have the .SUBCKT definition for the Winding?

Comment: @ThePhoton No  unless it's in the link somewhere that I missed

Comment: I think it's there. The last code section before what you shared.

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh, it is. I'll take a looksie.

Comment: May as well link [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260510/has-ltspice-been-extended-to-support-the-modified-chan-non-linear-hysteretic-mo) as it also discusses Chan.

Comment: Good thing I saw this in time... I don't know if you solved it, but in case you didn't, if you look closely at the "core-only" symbol, you'll see its middle point different than the one used together with the windings -- that's a connection pin (the point `C` in the picture right above the section shown in your picture, in the ltwiki link).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I never did get it working satisfactorily

Comment: @DKNguyen It has its quirks, [like the other alternatives](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/326442/95619), but, IMHO, it's the easiest to work with and gives good results. However, I only ever use it when I know there's saturation involved, otherwise coupled inductors will do just fine (as long as you make sure to check the currents).